# Find Data Attribute and add Class

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Been trying to figure this out. I want to have a user click on an a href , get the data attribute of that a href, and then find the class that matches that data attribute in the DOM (It will be an li, and add an active class to it.

Heres my js so far, I've tried 100 different things:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    var dataitem = $(this).data('item');
    $('ul li').find(dataitem).addClass('active');
    console.log(dataitem);
});
```

HMTL:

```
<ul class="anim cf">
    <li class="first active">
        <span class="drop"></span>
        <a href="#" data-item="first"></a>
        <a href="#" data-item="second"></a>
        <a href="#" data-item="four"></a>
    </li>   
<li class="second">
        <span class="drop"></span>
        <a href="#" data-item="first"></a>
        <a href="#" data-item="second"></a>
        <a href="#" data-item="four"></a>
    </li>   
<li class="third">
        <span class="drop"></span>
        <a href="#" data-item="first"></a>
        <a href="#" data-item="second"></a>
        <a href="#" data-item="four"></a>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().removeClass('active');` may produce undesired results.  You may want to use `$('ul li.active').removeClass('active')` or something similar. Edit: Personally I like something like this: `$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 2):

`.find()` method allows to search through the descendants of the element specified in the selector but in your case `.find()` will not work.

Try This :-

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e){
    $('ul li.active').removeClass('active'); //remove '.active' class from all li's
    var dataitem = $(this).data('item');
    $('ul li.' + dataitem).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/82ju6da9/1/)